# Cannot find CDI plugin for IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, intellij-idea, cdi

I'm new to Java and the IntelliJ IDEA, so this may be a stupid question, but I can't find / install the [Java EE Context and Dependency Injection](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/context-and-dependency-injection-cdi.html) plugin.

I'm using version 15.0.6 of the IDEA (because of another plugin I need to use, OS Gosu, which isn't available for the latest version.

I've looked in the plugin repositories through the Plugins section of Settings, and when I couldn't find it, checked the [IntelliJ IDEA Plugins](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/) directory, and still can't find it.

I've checked as much as I know how to do within the IDEA itself, and I'm fairly sure it's not installed (@Inject annotation isn't recognised, and it's not available to add as a framework).

So, am I missing something obvious? Am I looking in the wrong place? Has it ceased to exist?

Comment: Are you using Intellij community? Because I guess CDI as part of the JEE specification is only included in the Ultimate edition

Comment: Shi... ok, I hadn't considered that. I'm too used to working with .Net and Visual Studio